# malloc and ptr = (int*) malloc(100 * sizeof(int))

Tags: c

how malloc with `ptr = (int*) malloc(100 * sizeof(int))` can be allocating dynamic memory allocation. Should not it be static memory allocation.

https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-dynamic-memory-allocation

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: How can it be static if you have to make a function call to get it?

Comment: why do you think it should be static memory allocation?

Comment: Unfortunately this is now on hold. You are confusing as to what 'dynamic' means. It isn't only a question as to whether the size of the memory allocated is fixed or not. Generally automatic (heap) allocation requires the size to be fixed. Dynamic allocation can use a fixed or variable size. You might want to use dynamic allocation of a fixed size in several circumstances - large amount of memory, memory persistence, recursive function.

Comment: Was confused between the memory needed by array and pointer. if "int array_1[10]" saves 4*10=40 bytes and "int *ptr" "ptr = (cast *)malloc(4*int (*ptr))" saves 4*4=16 bytes. These are both are saving memory slots in buffer. What is difference????? –

Answer (score 1):

Your pointer can be static. Malloced memory is always dynamic

Comment: Was confused between the memory needed by array and pointer.  if "int array_1[10]" saves 4*10=40 bytes and "int *ptr"                 "ptr = (cast *)malloc(4*int (*ptr))"  saves 4*4=16 bytes.      These are both are saving memory slots in buffer.  What is difference?????

Comment: Malloc allocated memory on the heap dynamically during the runtime. The first arrays in you example are placed on the stack (auto variables) or in the static variablrs storage area. In the fact if the compiler supports variable length arrays automatic variables can be allocated dynamically as well. The difference is the location